# Chart Visual Studio disappears after postback

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web, charts, autopostback

i develop a website with VS2010.I have added a chart from toolbox that displays a line after a button is clicked.But while the chart appears fine the time i press the button, after a PostBack (for example i change the content of a textbox) the chart disappears.How can i make the chart keep showing after a PostBack?

Comment: can show some code? Are you checking IsPostBack before binding data?

Answer (score 9):

set EnableViewState="true"

```
<asp:Chart runat="server" ID="Chart1" EnableViewState="true">
```

Dunno why but asp.net charts seem to have viewstate off by default

Comment: it must generate a massive amount of jibberish in __viewstate.